# Jetty searching for webdefault.xml in wrong directories

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, server, jetty-9

I have been working with Jetty for a week and I have Maven handling the management. I have been successfully getting my program to run and work on my local computer, but when I try to deploy the app to a server, I keep getting this issue after running the command:

```
 java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar
```

> 2018-07-24 14:33:48.808:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup
>   of context
>   o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3224f60b{/,file:/var/lib/jetty9/webapps/root/,null}{/root}
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/etc/webdefault.xml (Not
>   a directory)  at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)     at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)    at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.FileResource.getInputStream(FileResource.java:290)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Descriptor.parse(Descriptor.java:54)    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebDescriptor.parse(WebDescriptor.java:207)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.setDefaults(MetaData.java:171)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.preConfigure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:53)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:468)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:504)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:440)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:560)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:235)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1255)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:321)    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:817)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:112)
>
> 2018-07-24 14:33:48.877:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup
>   of context
>   o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@76f2b07d{/ProjectName,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-ProjectName.war-_ProjectName-any-8365660038169967261.dir/webapp/,null}{/ProjectName.war}
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/etc/webdefault.xml (Not
>   a directory)  at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)     at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)    at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.FileResource.getInputStream(FileResource.java:290)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Descriptor.parse(Descriptor.java:54)    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebDescriptor.parse(WebDescriptor.java:207)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.setDefaults(MetaData.java:171)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.preConfigure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:53)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:468)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:504)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:455)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:560)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:235)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1255)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:321)    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:817)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:112)

My webdefault is located in usr/share/jetty9/etc folder, but it keeps looking in java and I have looking into the xml files there, trying to find a way to redirect the location so that it does not look into /usr/share/java/etc/.
Thank you

Comment: How did You install Java and jetty?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I followed a tutorial online. What the command I used was `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer` and I installed jetty with `sudo apt-get install jetty9`

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen if it helps, the result of `java -version` is `java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)`

Comment: Awesome. I got it working. Jetty-runner installation also helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jetty installation is broken. Uninstall it and download an official tar ball instead.

After starting the server and you see it running, you should be able to deploy your war file

Answer (score 0):

You can try different deployment options e.g

java -jar jetty-runner-9.4.0.M1.jar jetty-app/target/jetty-app.war

Options are given in doc - http://www.baeldung.com/deploy-to-jetty

Comment: So this may be a dumb question. My folder hierarchy is /usr/share/jetty9, where jetty9 has files bin/, default-root/, etc, lib/, logs, modules/, resources/, start.d, start.ini, start.jar and webapps/ which contains my .war file. I only have to provide the war file, correct? Or do i have to clone my project to the server?

Comment: You need to provide war file only.